# Splash Screen Android - Count Down Timer Display

Tags: java, android, splash-screen, countdown, android-screen

I am trying to use splash screen for my app. 
I want to display Count down timer in my splash screen.
So far I am able to achieve the splash screen working but don't know how to display count down timer. I created layout for count down timer. I want splash screen to stay for 5 Hours then take to the next activity.

**Splashactivity.java**

```
   public class splash_screen extends AppCompatActivity {
    private float imageAplha = 1f;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        //splashScreenUseTimer(5000);
        splashScreenUseAsyncTask();
    }


    // Show splash screen until network load data complete.
    private void splashScreenUseAsyncTask()
    {
        // Create a AsyncTask object.
        final RetrieveDateTask retrieveDateTask = new RetrieveDateTask();
        retrieveDateTask.execute("", "", "");
        // Get splash image view object.
        final ImageView splashImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_id);

        // Create a count down timer object.It will count down every 0.1 seconds and last for milliSeconds milliseconds..
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 100) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                // Reduce the splash screen background image's alpha value for each count down.
                splashImageView.setAlpha(imageAplha);
                imageAplha -= 0.1;
                if(imageAplha <= 0)
                {
                    imageAplha = 1;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // When count down complete, set the image to invisible.
                imageAplha = 0;
                splashImageView.setAlpha(imageAplha);

                // If AsyncTask is not complete, restart the counter to count again.
                if(!retrieveDateTask.isAsyncTaskComplete()) {
                    this.start();
                }
            }
        };
        // Start the count down timer.
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    // This is the async task class that get data from network.
    private class RetrieveDateTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        // Indicate whether AsyncTask complete or not.
        private boolean asyncTaskComplete = false;

        public boolean isAsyncTaskComplete() {
            return asyncTaskComplete;
        }

        public void setAsyncTaskComplete(boolean asyncTaskComplete) {
            this.asyncTaskComplete = asyncTaskComplete;
        }

        // This method will be called before AsyncTask run.
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.asyncTaskComplete = false;
        }

        // This method will be called when AsyncTask run.
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                // Simulate a network operation which will last for 10 seconds.
                Thread currTread = Thread.currentThread();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    currTread.sleep(1000);
                }
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                return null;
            }
        }

        // This method will be called after AsyncTask run.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            // Start SplashScreenMainActivity.
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(splash_screen.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            splash_screen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            // Close SplashScreenActivity.
            splash_screen.this.finish();
            this.asyncTaskComplete = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_id"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ts_logo"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_hour"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_hour_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Hour"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_minute"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_minute_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Minute"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_second"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_second_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Second"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@contact dummy I edited @Dev code with small modification.try this one. Based on your animation requirement increase and decrease imageAlpha size.

```
private float imageAplha = 1f;
private boolean imageStatus = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    splashScreenUseAsyncTask();
}


// Show splash screen until network load data complete.
private void splashScreenUseAsyncTask()
{
    // Create a AsyncTask object.
    final RetrieveDateTask retrieveDateTask = new RetrieveDateTask();
    retrieveDateTask.execute("", "", "");
    // Get splash image view object.
    final ImageView splashImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_id);
    final TextView tv_hour = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_hour);
    final TextView tv_minute = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_minute);
    final TextView tv_second = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_second);

    // Create a count down timer object.It will count down every 0.1 seconds and last for milliSeconds milliseconds..
    final int time= 3600000*5;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {


            long Days = l / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            long Hours = l / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
            long Minutes = l / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            long Seconds = l / 1000 % 60;
            //
          //  tv_days.setText(String.format("%02d", Days));
            tv_hour.setText(String.format("%02d", Hours));
            tv_minute.setText(String.format("%02d", Minutes));
            tv_second.setText(String.format("%02d", Seconds));

            splashImageView.setAlpha(imageAplha);


            if(imageStatus){
                imageAplha += 1;
                if(imageAplha >= 1)
                {
                   // imageAplha-= 0.5;
                    imageStatus =  false;
                }
            }else{
                imageAplha -= 1;
                if(imageAplha <= 0)
                {

                    imageStatus =  true;
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // When count down complete, set the image to invisible.
            imageAplha = 0;
            splashImageView.setAlpha(imageAplha);

            // If AsyncTask is not complete, restart the counter to count again.
            if(!retrieveDateTask.isAsyncTaskComplete()) {
                this.start();
            }
        }
    };
    // Start the count down timer.
    countDownTimer.start();
}

// This is the async task class that get data from network.
private class RetrieveDateTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    // Indicate whether AsyncTask complete or not.
    private boolean asyncTaskComplete = false;

    public boolean isAsyncTaskComplete() {
        return asyncTaskComplete;
    }

    public void setAsyncTaskComplete(boolean asyncTaskComplete) {
        this.asyncTaskComplete = asyncTaskComplete;
    }

    // This method will be called before AsyncTask run.
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.asyncTaskComplete = false;
    }

    // This method will be called when AsyncTask run.
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            // Simulate a network operation which will last for 10 seconds.
            Thread currTread = Thread.currentThread();
            for (int i = 0; i < 18000000; i++) {
                currTread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // This method will be called after AsyncTask run.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        // Start SplashScreenMainActivity.
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(splash_screen .this,
                MainActvity.class);
        splash_screen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
        // Close SplashScreenActivity.
        splash_screen.this.finish();
        this.asyncTaskComplete = true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

@contact dummy  I have edited your code try using this

```
// Show splash screen until network load data complete.
private void splashScreenUseAsyncTask()
{
    // Create a AsyncTask object.
    final RetrieveDateTask retrieveDateTask = new RetrieveDateTask();
    retrieveDateTask.execute("", "", "");
    // Get splash image view object.
    final ImageView splashImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_id);

     //for 5 Hours 
    final int time= 3600000*5;          
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {


                    long Days = l / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                    long Hours = l / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
                    long Minutes = l / (60 * 1000) % 60;
                    long Seconds = l / 1000 % 60;
                    //
                    tv_days.setText(String.format("%02d", Days));
                    tv_hour.setText(String.format("%02d", Hours));
                    tv_minute.setText(String.format("%02d", Minutes));
                    tv_second.setText(String.format("%02d", Seconds));

            splashImageView.setAlpha(imageAplha);
            imageAplha -= 0.1;
            if(imageAplha <= 0)
            {
                imageAplha = 1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // When count down complete, set the image to invisible.
            imageAplha = 0;
            splashImageView.setAlpha(imageAplha);

            // If AsyncTask is not complete, restart the counter to count again.
            if(!retrieveDateTask.isAsyncTaskComplete()) {
                this.start();
            }
        }
    };
    // Start the count down timer.
    countDownTimer.start();
}
```

Comment: I did exactly what you did here. But I am facing two problem it take to the next activity after 10 seconds. It should wait to finish whole 5 hours and second issue is my logo image used to have heatbeat effect  like fade in and out. Now it fade in and out very slowly. How to increase speed.

Comment: @contactdummy put startActivity(SplashActivity.this,NextActivity.class); inside onFinished() ;

Comment: @contactdummy instead of thread.sleep() use Handler that will not affect on your animation.

Comment: check whether I did it in right way. I edited your code.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you are trying to do because in the edited code it shows something else

Comment: Basically I want splash screen which give me count down timer and image fade in and out effect . After 5 hours it should take to the next activity.